Any performance benefits of using ALIGN 16 to align functions to a 16-Byte boundary in assembly?
I'm curious whether aligning performance-critical assembly functions to a 16-byte boundary is truly beneficial, or if it's just a micro-optimization that can be safely ignored nowadays?
For example, consider these MASM functions below:
align16.asm
.686P
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

includelib libcmt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

printf PROTO NEAR C,:DWORD,:BYTE

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello World %c",13,10,0

.code

nop

;ALIGN 16

MyFunA PROC
    invoke  printf,ADDR HelloWorld,'A'
    ret         
MyFunA ENDP

nop

;ALIGN 16

MyFunB PROC
    invoke  printf,ADDR HelloWorld,'B'
    ret         
MyFunB ENDP

main PROC NEAR C
    invoke  MyFunA
    invoke  MyFunB
    ret
main ENDP
END

Without ALIGN 16
When ALIGN 16 is not used, the functions are laid out consecutively without any padding:
  00401000: 90                 nop
_MyFunA@0:
  00401001: 6A 41              push        41h
  00401003: 68 00 A0 45 00     push        45A000h
  00401008: E8 7B 1D 00 00     call        _printf
  0040100D: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00401010: C3                 ret
  00401011: 90                 nop
_MyFunB@0:
  00401012: 6A 42              push        42h
  00401014: 68 00 A0 45 00     push        45A000h
  00401019: E8 6A 1D 00 00     call        _printf
  0040101E: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00401021: C3                 ret

With ALIGN 16
After uncommenting ALIGN 16, the assembler inserts padding to align the functions on 16-byte boundaries:
  00401000: 90                 nop
  00401001: 8D A4 24 00 00 00  lea         esp,[esp] ; <---|
            00                                       ;     |
  00401008: 8D A4 24 00 00 00  lea         esp,[esp] ;     |- Padding
            00                                       ;     |
  0040100F: 90                 nop                   ; <---|
_MyFunA@0:
  00401010: 6A 41              push        41h
  00401012: 68 00 A0 45 00     push        45A000h
  00401017: E8 8B 1D 00 00     call        _printf
  0040101C: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  0040101F: C3                 ret
  00401020: 90                 nop
  00401021: 8D A4 24 00 00 00  lea         esp,[esp] ; <---|
            00                                       ;     |
  00401028: 8D A4 24 00 00 00  lea         esp,[esp] ;     |- Padding
            00                                       ;     |
  0040102F: 90                 nop                   ; <---|
_MyFunB@0:
  00401030: 6A 42              push        42h
  00401032: 68 00 A0 45 00     push        45A000h
  00401037: E8 6B 1D 00 00     call        _printf
  0040103C: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  0040103F: C3                 ret

Build.bat
Here’s the batch script used to assemble, link, and disassemble the code:
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat" x86
)

ml.exe /c /coff /W3 /Sa /Zi /Zd /Flalign16.lst align16.asm
link.exe /DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console align16.obj
dumpbin /DISASM align16.exe > align16.txt

Related to Function code aligned to 16 bytes

The explanation for why it is beneficial that is given in the related question still applies. Yes, instruction fetch still happens in aligned 16 byte blocks. Yes, instruction fetching and decoding is still a major bottleneck for many codes

It still applies nowadays. Decoders are faster and most CPU have a (pretty large) µop cache so the effect is certainly smaller than >10 years-ago but it is still important for performance (and 16 byte is really tiny on modern platforms). You may see some benefit with 64-bit alignement in some pathological case. The performance gain mainly happen when caches are cold (e.g. first execution after a context switch or even after executing large codes or doing a lot of jumps)

Regarding the kind of application you write you may see either no benefit or a significant impact. For example, numerical application doing number crunching are likely not effected, while complex parsers with big tables should be pretty impacted. OOP code with many different virtual functions can also be strongly affected. Note the alignment of the jump instruction and loop also matter (actually certainly more).

The main advantage is a slightly lower latency on function entry, as the decoder is likely to be able to decode more instructions in the first cycle if it can decode full 16 bytes than if the code was misaligned.

Depending on the program, I've had conflicting results, align 16 is sometimes faster and sometimes slower. I suspect that the slower case occurs when without the align 16, the relevant code fits within one less cache line.

basically already said but the alignment of the entry point is one thing but where loops land (not necessarily on a boundary but tuning of each loop) can have a bigger impact, but has to be tuned and you would put nops in to move that loops alignment within the function.  (if you can measure any of this on an x86.  More efficient, higher performance architectures you can definitely see this)
